# Back button on stack navigator freezes until all apis in component finish loading

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

In my React native application, I am using [stack-navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/)

I have implemented a back button like the following.

```
<Stack.Screen 
    name="Charts"
    component={Charts}
    options={{
        title: 'Charts',
        headerLeft: () => (
            <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} p={4}>
                <Icon as={Entypo} name='chevron-left' size={26} color={'primary.400'} />
            </Pressable>
        )
    }}
/>
```

In my component, I am calling 4 APIs that load some charts. The problem I am facing is that the touch on the back button responds only after all the APIs finish loading.

I tried different approaches. One of them is `SafeAreaView.`To ensure that the scrolling area is only within the content area of the screen, leaving space for the back button. Something like this.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
    {/* Your content here */}
    <Text>Content goes here</Text>
  </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Then I tried wrapping the screen component inside a **`React.memo`** Higher-Order Component (HOC) to prevent unnecessary re-renders.

`export default React.memo(MyScreenComponent);`

I also went through [header-related-options](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#header-related-options), and tried different combinations but couldn't come up with a perfect combination.

---

***UPDATE :***

So it turned out that loading svg images using SvgXml is stopping the back button to do expected.

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
    {/* Your content here */}
    <Text>Content goes here</Text>
    <Text>Following line is causing the issue.</Text>
    <SvgXml xml={xml} viewBox={`0 0 350 330`} />
</ScrollView>
```

I am still trying to figure out how to load the images asynchronously using SvgXml or an alternative solution.